# i need a function where i can bar character input , i need only integer input from user

Tags: c

```
 case 'f':
            printf ("Great!!! lets create your fixed account\n");

        printf ("\nA minimum purchase of 1000 units is required for this

 account\n");
            printf ("\nPrice per unit as of Sep. 15 is $52.69\n")
;
            printf ("\nPlease enter required amount of units\n");

            scanf("%d",&amount);


            if (isdigit(amount))

                {
                printf ("invalid input\n");
                success = 'f';
                break;
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried the isdigit, isalpha function but none works

Comment: And did you follow the suggestions in the comments of your other question? Because there was a clear explanation on how to use `scanf` to see if an integer value was read.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [doc on scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), then change your code to check the return value from your call to scanf.  Is digit(amount) can only succeed if the user enters a value that matches a character in the current code page, so stop calling it.